# Redis Server connection

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, redis

I am trying to run my node/express app on AWS EC2 but am getting errors from Redis, it will not connect to the server and I am not sure what the problem is??

Here is the error I get after the command "npm run production"

Is there a special configuration when running Redis remotely vs locally?

Thank you!

**ERROR**

```
[ec2-user@ip-000-00-00-00 application-node-app]$ npm run production

> task-manager@1.0.0 production
> env-cmd -f ./config/prod.env nodemon src/index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
server is live on port 3000
Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
127.0.0.1:6379
// 9x Redis retry errors, all identical
```

**REDIS CODE**

```
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`)
const redis = require(`redis`)
const util = require(`util`)
const redisUrl = `redis://127.0.0.1:6379`
const client = redis.createClient(redisUrl)
client.hget = util.promisify(client.hget)
const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec

client.on("error", function (err) { 
    console.log("Error " + err);
});


mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function(options = {}) {
    
    this.useCache = true

    this.hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || `default`)

    return this 
}

mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function () {
    if (!this.useCache) {
        return exec.apply(this, arguments)
    }
    const key = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, this.getQuery(), {
        collection: this.mongooseCollection.name
    }))

    const cacheValue = await client.hget(this.hashKey, key)

    if (cacheValue) {
        console.log(`cached DATA!`)
        const doc = JSON.parse(cacheValue)
        return Array.isArray(doc) ? doc.map(d => new this.model(d)) : new this.model(doc)
        
    }

    const result = await exec.apply(this, arguments)

    client.hset(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result), `EX`, 10)
    return result
    
}

module.exports = {
    clearHash(hashKey) {
        client.del(JSON.stringify(hashKey))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any change in redis to run it locally or remotely.

What you need to make sure instead is, Do you have connectivity to redis from your EC2 instance.

Worst case you can try installing redis-cli on to the EC2 instance and figure out from there. I believe it might be port forwarding issue or IP Tables issue.

You should of course restart from a fresh EC2 instance once the testing is done.

Edit: One thing I wish to add here though, Even though I said there is no change in redis, make sure that it's bound on 0.0.0.0 and not on 127.0.0.1 and make sure to check the port config